# PHP Daemon for executing sudo commands with Upstart

Tags: php, linux, upstart, ubuntu-14.04

I need to execute some sudo commands like CHOWN over files created with Apache.
After a lot of research - I found about the Upstart and creating a PHP Daemon that can act as a background process which keeps track of the DB and if any new entries are created, the daemon file executes to change the file permissions and owner.

(Cron doesn't cut it for me as I need a lesser interval than a minute. Got into weird errors because chown took longer than a minute and multiple instances of the same script)

The chown command takes a long time to run if there are a lot of files. 
My issue is - I need to update the entries back in the DB that the permissions/owner has been changed successfully to update the user.

```
exec ( 'chown -R '.$newuser.':'.$newuser.' '.$folder.' > /dev/null &');
```

This runs chown in the background but I need to know when the process ends.
The only way I can think of to achieve that is get the PID of the new process and track its status at regular intervals but I got stuck there (not sure how to get the PID exactly).

Also, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You use supervisor approach. Supervisor is a parent process of a forked process. When forked child process exits, the parent catches its exit signal. That's how you know that process died / exited ok and you can take appropriate action. That means your child would execute chown, and once done you just exit(0). At that point the parent catches the exit signal. The other thing you can do is use an event loop and simply implement timed event to get executed every N seconds. The jobs created using the event loop can be farmed out to a pool of workers.

Comment: Ok, so I need to create a new process from this daemon say every N seconds.. then the child process forks a new process and waits for the exit signal?